Running Milvus in cluster mode
I want to run Milvus on my local cluster.
I thought to use docker compose file and docker stack/docker swarm, but when I run my compose file something is not working. I can see all services started on the target nodes but for some reason milvus-proxy listening port is not available.
$ docker ps | grep milvus_milvus-proxy
854486cdb68a   milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10                "/tini -- milvus run…"   51 seconds ago   Up 49 seconds    **NO PORT HERE**    milvus_milvus-proxy.1.jzkt5tq8ck1fq34lx9odgr2jp

minio & etcd listening ports are shown in the docker ps output
These are the steps I've made:
I defined a master node and joined a worker using docker swarm
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <master-ip>
docker swarm join --token <token> <master-ip>

Then I defined the compose file:
services:
  etcd:
    image: quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.5.5
    container_name: etcd
    environment:
      - ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_RETENTION=1
      - ETCD_QUOTA_BACKEND_BYTES=4294967296
      - ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION=yes
      - ETCDCTL_API=3
    ports:
      - "2379:2379"
      - "2380:2380"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
    command: minio server /minio_data
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_VOLUME_DIRECTORY:-.}/volumes/minio:/minio_data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-proxy:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-proxy
    command: ["milvus", "run", "proxy"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    ports:
      - "<master_node_ip>:19530:19530"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-rootcoord:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-rootcoord
    command: ["milvus", "run", "rootcoord"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-datacoord:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-datacoord
    command: ["milvus", "run", "datacoord"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-indexcoord:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-indexcoord
    command: ["milvus", "run", "indexcoord"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-querycoord:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-querycoord
    command: ["milvus", "run", "querycoord"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-datanode-1:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-datanode-1
    command: ["milvus", "run", "datanode"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-datanode-2:
     --same as milvus-datanode-1 config --
        constraints: [node.hostname == worker_node]

  milvus-indexnode-1:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-indexnode-1
    command: ["milvus", "run", "indexnode"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-indexnode-2:
    --same as milvus-indexnode-1 config --
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == worker_node]

  milvus-querynode-1:
    image: milvusdb/milvus:v2.2.10
    container_name: milvus-querynode-1
    command: ["milvus", "run", "querynode"]
    environment:
      ETCD_ENDPOINTS: <master_node_ip>:2379
      MINIO_ADDRESS: <master_node_ip>:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: 0
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == master_node]

  milvus-querynode-2:
  --same as milvus-querynode-1 config --
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == worker_node]

volumes:
  minio-data:

And these are the milvus-proxy logs:
["Proxy internal server listen on tcp"] [port=19529]
[2024/07/11 15:35:05.996 +00:00] [INFO] [proxy/service.go:263] ["Proxy internal server already listen on tcp"] [port=19529]
[2024/07/11 15:35:05.996 +00:00] [INFO] [proxy/service.go:281] ["create Proxy internal grpc server"] ["enforcement policy"="{\"MinTime\":5000000000,\"PermitWithoutStream\":true}"] ["server parameters"="{\"MaxConnectionIdle\":0,\"MaxConnectionAge\":0,\"MaxConnectionAgeGrace\":0,\"Time\":60000000000,\"Timeout\":10000000000}"]
[2024/07/11 15:35:05.996 +00:00] [INFO] [proxy/service.go:155] ["Proxy server listen on tcp"] [port=19530]
[2024/07/11 15:35:05.996 +00:00] [INFO] [proxy/service.go:162] ["Proxy server already listen on tcp"] [port=19530]
[2024/07/11 15:35:05.996 +00:00] [INFO] [proxy/service.go:170] ["Get proxy rate limiter done"] [port=19530]
[2024/07/11 15:35:05.996 +00:00] [INFO] [proxy/service.go:233] ["create Proxy grpc server"] ["enforcement policy"="{\"MinTime\":5000000000,\"PermitWithoutStream\":true}"] ["server parameters"="{\"MaxConnectionIdle\":0,\"MaxConnectionAge\":0,\"MaxConnectionAgeGrace\":0,\"Time\":60000000000,\"Timeout\":10000000000}"]
[2024/07/11 15:35:05.996 +00:00] [INFO] [proxy/service.go:363] ["register http server of proxy"]


I've used the example from here
I run it on a single machine and it worked. I think it can be extended easily to work on multiple machine (Need to dispatch with docker swarm).
From what I see my compose file was missing of a distributed messaging framework.
The example compose file is using Apache Pulsar for communication between the services from what I understand.
